# Access VBA SQL command INSERT for multiple value

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2016

I need to add values to column in table in VBA Access.
But column is number and lookup (from other table) and  multiple value

I tried many commands:

```
 Private Sub buttRec_Click()
   Dim db As DAO.Database
 
   strSQL = "INSERT INTO TABB (BNUM) VAULE (3)"
   Set db = CurrentDb
   db.Execute strSQL
   Set db = Nothing
 End Sub
```

options for strSQL which I tried:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO TABB (BNUM) VALUES (1), (2), (3);"
strSQL = "INSERT INTO TABB (BNUM) VALUES (1,2,3);"
strSQL = "INSERT INTO TABB (BNUM) VALUES ('1,2,3');"
strSQL = "INSERT INTO TABB (BNUM) VALUES (1;2;3);"
strSQL = "INSERT INTO TABB (BNUM) VALUES ('1;2;3');"
strSQL = "INSERT INTO TABB (BNUM) SELECT '1' UNION SELECT '3'"
strSQL = "INSERT INTO TABB (BNUM) SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 3"
```

How to do this?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Yes exactly BNUM is lookup (from other table) and multiple value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some examples for MultiValue fields.
INSERT and DELETE

Test data:
table `TABB` with columns `Id` - primary key, `RowName` - text,`BNUM` - multivalued field.

Insert row to table

```
INSERT INTO TABB ( RowName )
VALUES ("New row 1");
```

Insert new value to multivalued field

```
INSERT INTO TABB (BNUM.[Value])
VALUES (11)
WHERE TABB.RowName="New row 1";
```

Insert second value to multivalued field

```
INSERT INTO TABB (BNUM.[Value])
VALUES (22)
WHERE TABB.RowName="New row 1";
```

Insert next value to multivalued field

```
INSERT INTO TABB (BNUM.[Value])
VALUES (1)
WHERE TABB.Id=1;
```

Values in BNUM mast be unique.

Insert from subquery

```
INSERT INTO TABB ( MField.Value )
SELECT  MainValue *10 from (select DISTINCT MainValue FROM Head)
WHERE ((([RowName])="New row 1"));
```

Multiple value fields operations thru Recordset.
Examples for Add and Delete operations

```
Public Function TestMulti() As String
Dim rsTab As Recordset
Dim rsM As Recordset
    Set rsTab = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbTestMulti WHERE MultiName='New row 1'", dbOpenDynaset)
    If Not (rsTab.EOF And rsTab.BOF) Then
        rsTab.Edit
        ' access to multivalued field members thru recordset !
        Set rsM = rsTab!MField.Value

        With rsM
            .AddNew
            !Value = "New prog value1"
            .Update
            
            .AddNew
            !Value = "New prog value2"
            .Update
        End With
        rsTab.Update
    End If
    TestMulti="Ok"
End Function

Public Function TestMulti2() As String
Dim rsTab As Recordset
Dim rsM As Recordset
    Set rsTab = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbTestMulti WHERE MultiName='New row 1'", dbOpenDynaset)
    If Not (rsTab.EOF And rsTab.BOF) Then
        rsTab.Edit
        Set rsM = rsTab!MField.Value
        rsM.FindFirst "Value = 'New prog value1'"
        If Not rsM.NoMatch Then
            With rsM
                .Delete
            End With
        End If
        rsTab.Update
    End If
    TestMulti2="Ok"
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing one insert per row you wish to insert in a loop is an option:

```
Private Sub buttRec_Click()
   Dim db As DAO.Database
 
   Set db = CurrentDb
   For i = 1 To 3
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO Tabb (BNUM) VALUES (" & i & ")"
        db.Execute strSQL
   Next i
   Set db = Nothing
 End Sub
```

This will be slow if you have a large number of rows to add, but for a few, this will be very quick.

Optionally you could use that UNION query route you were headed down and hijack another table to keep it from throwing an error.

```
INSERT INTO Tabb (BNUM)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 1 as BNUM FROM MSysObjects
    UNION ALL SELECT TOP 1 2 FROM MSysObjects
    UNION ALL SELECT TOP 1 3 FROM MSysObjects
   ) dt
```